# Sum the values according to labels in R

Tags: r

How do I draw the sum value of each class represented like the table:

```
    a    a,b    a,b,c    c
    5     2       1      2
```

E.g for the above example expected result is:

```
    a    b    c
    8    3    3
```

I'm asking this since I couldn't even find a close solution anywhere in the stackoverflow, the closest solution represented was the [dcast function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428960/how-can-i-sum-values-of-columns-with-dcast), but that only checks for equality, not presence.

Comment: Urg, that's ugly, but using `tidyr` and `dplyr`: `dat %>% gather(var, val) %>% separate_rows(var, sep = ',') %>% group_by(var) %>% summarise(val = sum(val)) %>% spread(var, val)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using base R,

```
sapply(unique(unlist(strsplit(names(df), '\\.'))), function(i) 
                                  sum(df[grepl(i, names(df))]))
#a b c 
#8 3 3
```

Note: I used `\\.` for `strsplit` instead of `,` since names were read like that.