# Sum the values of a 2 dimensional table according to labels in R

Tags: r

Coming from [Sum the values according to labels in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068726/sum-the-values-according-to-labels-in-r/38069185#38069185).

I've been notified that working with 2 dimensional tables is rather significantly different with 1 dimensional ones, like:

```
     a    a,b    a,b,c    c
 d   5     2       1      2
d,e  2     1       1      1
```

And we want to achieve:

```
     a    b    c
d    12   5    5
e    4    2    2
```

So how can this be achieved using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit convoluted, but it should work :

```
m <- as.matrix(data.frame('a'=c(5,2),'a,b'=c(2,1),
                          'a,b,c'=c(1:1),'c'=c(2,1),
                          check.names = FALSE,row.names=c('d','d,e')))
colNamesSplits <- strsplit(colnames(m),',')
rowNamesSplits <- strsplit(rownames(m),',')

colNms <- unique(unlist(colNamesSplits))
rowNms <- unique(unlist(rowNamesSplits))

colIdxs <- unlist(sapply(1:length(colNamesSplits),
                         function(i) rep.int(i,length(colNamesSplits[[i]]))))
rowIdxs <- unlist(sapply(1:length(rowNamesSplits),
                         function(i) rep.int(i,length(rowNamesSplits[[i]]))))
colIdxsMapped <- unlist(sapply(colNamesSplits, function(n) match(n,colNms)))
rowIdxsMapped <- unlist(sapply(rowNamesSplits, function(n) match(n,rowNms)))

# let's create the fully expanded matrix
expanded <- as.matrix(m[rowIdxs,colIdxs])
rownames(expanded) <- rowNms[rowIdxsMapped]
colnames(expanded) <- colNms[colIdxsMapped]

# aggregate expanded by cols :
expanded <- do.call(cbind,lapply(split(1:ncol(expanded),colnames(expanded)),
                 function(ii) rowSums(expanded[,ii,drop=FALSE])))
# aggregate expanded by rows :
expanded <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(1:nrow(expanded),rownames(expanded)),
                 function(ii) colSums(expanded[ii,,drop=FALSE])))

> expanded
   a b c
d 12 5 5
e  4 2 2
```

Comment: Excuse me if I interrupt, but what is this "DF"? I mean did u mean "m" the original matrix?

Comment: @lkn2993: yes sorry it's a typo (initially m matrix was called DF).Fixed ;)